# Maven modules dependency an IoC issues

Tags: spring, maven, inversion-of-control

I have three Maven modules :

- Dao (containing DAO interfaces),
- DaoImpl (containing DAO classes implementing Dao),
- Service (containing services using DaoImpl objects).

The dependencies between the three modules are like this :

DaoImpl -> Dao <- Service

'->' means 'depends on'

I'd like to inject DaoImpl beans into Service beans. The problem is that since Service is not depending on DaoImpl, it can't access its classpath. Hence, the DaoImpl beans declared in Service can't be autowired to the beans declared in the application context of DaoImpl.

One solution is to make Service dependent on DaoImpl.

Dao <- DaoImpl <- Service

But in this cas, there will be no meaning of having interfaces for the DAOs. The module Dao will be no longer required and DaoImpl will be exposed.

Do you have any arguments about this subject?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you should introduce fourth module which depends on dao, (one of) daoimpl, and service.

It's sort of 'application deployment' module - typically WAR or something similar.

- Application -> Service -> Dao
- Application -> DaoImpl -> Dao

The role of the Application module is primarily to prepare the complete classpath.

Comment: Ok. I see. And it will be that module the one who gives DaoImpl beans to Service module, isn't it?

Comment: yes, Application is the one that should wire all components together - be it java code or spring or anything else

Answer (score 0):

It can also be resolved by

```
Service
  |_DaoIface
  |_DaoImpl
```

Here spring can be loaded from the service so it has both IFace and Impl visible.

Since Impl is directly visible to the service, it doesn't mean that DaoIface is not necessary. It is your design decisions. If the DAOImpls implementation will change on run time or if there are any other component to which you want to expose your DAO layer, then iface will be handy.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Since I will have a web module, I think it will be the war that will manage the wiring.